Unable to run prisma client code in dockerized app
The error message shows that my model instance is undefined.
I find it weird because I've used the command npx prisma db push to generate the prisma client inside docker container.
I have confirmed that I've prisma/client as a dependency.
I really struggled to find an answer, but after hours of trying, I found no one having the issue where the model instance is undefined.
Please help.
Here's the relevant information for your reference.

The error

    Unhandled Runtime Error
    Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findMany')

Source
src/app/page.tsx (4:29) @ findMany

  2 |
  3 | export default async function Home() {
> 4 |   const data = await db.job.findMany({
    |                             ^
  5 |     where: {
  6 |       approved: true,
  7 |     },


Dockerfile(For the app)

FROM node:20.0
WORKDIR /app

ADD ./package.json .
RUN npm install
ADD . .
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]


docker-compose.yml

version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: next14-server-action
    build: ./
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres_jobs
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data:



The app where the prisma code is used

import db from "@/../prisma";

export default async function Home() {
  const data = await db.job.findMany({
    where: {
      approved: true,
    },
  });
  return <main className="">{data.toString()}</main>;


You don't seem to have actually included the error in the question.  Can you [edit] the question to include that?  (Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.)

Thank you for pointing that out. I've updated the post with the error. Could you have a look again?
